# Toggle EF5 Connections During Runtime

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I've got a project where in the UI I have a Radio Button list that consists of two elements: Development and Production.  In my project I'm using an EF5 Model with SProcs to accomplish database ops. I want to create a way to use the Radio buttons to toggle between Development and Production database servers during runtime but I cannot find a good way of doing this. All I need to do is replace the database server portion in the connection string located in app.config. Using Transforms does not appear to be an option here.

Is there a way I can accomplish this without having to reconstruct the EF ConnectionString?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use dependency injection and have two DbContext classes. Then based on the Radio button value, you can determine which DbContext to use.

Or in your DbContext constructor, you could pass in which connection string to use:

```
public class MyDbContext : DbContext
{
    public MyDbContext(string connStringName) : base("name=" + connStringName) { }
}
```

Comment: I was hoping to avoid having to add another EF Model just for production. But I'm not sure I follow your example because that code is normally auto-gen? Not sure if it is a good idea to change it? Kind of new to EF

Comment: Well altering the constructor for my context worked. I think I may just create an overload for it but your example got me going in the right direction.

Comment: Nice, glad it helped. That's the option I would go with too. There's quite a few reasons to modify the auto generated code. I would suggest taking a look at [this pluralsight course](http://pluralsight.com/training/Courses/TableOfContents/efarchitecture) as covers a lot of interesting scenarios with EF.

Comment: NOTE: It has come to my attention if you alter the auto-gen constructor you must make sure not to alter the EF Model otherwise your code will be overwritten as it auto-gens new entries.  Not sure how to overcome this but my app is small and specific so not much of an issue. However, if anyone has a suggestion besides adding two models (one for Prod and Dev) I'm all ears.

Comment: Ah, you must have done the model first or database first. I use code first generally, and don't have this issue. The outputs from the auto generated code are partial classes right? Couldn't you add your overload in another file that is also a partial class?